# How to display a list of text when hovering on a button?

Tags: html, css

As the title states, I would like to display a list of text (to be precise, name of 5-10 games) when I hover over the button.

**CSS:**

```
    .buttons a {
    float:left;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;

    }
    .buttons label {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    }
   .ghost-button {
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 48px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 78px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.0),rgba(0,0,0,0.0)),url(http://wallpapershome.com/images/pages/pic_hs/8253.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out,
    border-color 0.2s ease-out;
    }

   .ghost-button:hover {
   background: #333;
   color: white;
   font-size: 28px;
   text-align: center;
   transition: .5s ease;
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="ghost-button" href="#"><label>Horror</label></a>
</div>
```

I want the **label** to disappear after hovering. And I want to display a list of game names, preferably in **bullets**. The options of the **list** will be clickable i.e they will redirect the user to another page.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "And I want to display a list of game names, preferably in bullets." where's that code?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to achieve, sorry if the post confused you. I want to display a list (in bullets) after hovering over the buttons.  This is the page: http://game-finder.000webhostapp.com/topten.html

Comment: We're not going to go examine the source code of your web site. Please post the relevant code here, in your question.

Comment: Can you check it here https://jsfiddle.net/7o45schx/

Comment: Every piece of relevant code is present in the thread, shared the link to give you an idea of what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @VenoM you didn't include the list of links. You don't have to position it, but you can provide the markup you want to use so we don't have to guess and make something up for you. That's relevant to the problem.

Comment: Why don't you just edit your question and post it right here as a code snippet? This is the way Stack Overflow works. Don't make the people that are trying to help you have to go somewhere else to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list and have it set to display: none by default. Once the user hovers over .ghost-button the list will be visible and the default label will be hidden.

Here's how I did this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="ghost-button" href="#"><label>Horror</label>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons a {
    float:left;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.buttons label {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
}

.ghost-button {
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 48px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 78px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.0),rgba(0,0,0,0.0)),url(http://wallpapershome.com/images/pages/pic_hs/8253.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out,
    border-color 0.2s ease-out;
}

.ghost-button:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.ghost-button:hover label {
    display: none;
}

.ghost-button ul {
    display: none;
}

.ghost-button:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzOzaE

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pre-make whatever you want to show on hover and then default it to not show. Then using the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class selector, you can show it:

```css
div.hidden { display:none; }

/* Target the hidden div when the target div is being hovered over */
#trigger:hover + div.hidden {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="trigger">Hover over me</div>
<div class="hidden">I'm usually hidden</div>
```